# Wordpress WooCommerce Checkout - SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

One of our Wordpress sites is facing an issue on the **checkout page** of **WooCommerce**. When "Place Order" button is clicked an error triggers:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

This is the error that is shown in the console:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function update_status() on 
boolean in <b>/home/public_html/wp-
content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/gateways/bacs/class-wc-gateway-
bacs.php</b> on line <b>346</b><br />
```

- I have disabled all plugins except WooCommerce and the problem persists;
- I have tried default themes like TwentyThirteen and the problem persists;
- WooCommerce is up-to-date (Version 3.2.3);
- We have COD (Cash on Delivery) and Bank Transfer as options for payments.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Looks like it's trying to call the member function `update_status()` on `$order` but for whatever reasons, `$order` is a boolean (at guess, i'd say `false` as a result of a failure at `$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );` ). I'd start by looking at why `wc_get_order` is returning false, rather than an order object.

Comment: Any thoughts on how can I debug further than this?

Comment: Try to change your theme, there might some functions in the functions.php that interferes with order creation

Comment: I already tried changing the theme, as mentioned in the initial post. This hasn't solved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After debugging the code, I figured out that my problem was somewhere in the database, with the ID of the order that wasn't saved properly (The value passed was always 0). My guess is that some plugin messed up my database.

The **auto-increment was off in my database**, so the ID of the order couldn't be saved correctly, thus resulting the above error mentioned in the 1st post.

The solution was to **fix the database**, by adding **auto-increment** where it was needed and delete all the entries with 0 as ID in table **wp_posts**.

Comment: Gr8 solution bro

Answer (score 0):

I came across same issue for me it was folder permission issue which solved.

Comment: Which folder had the issue?